# Change default answer of clearcase findmerge command

Tags: unix, clearcase

From a terminal I type the following clearcase command.

```
Cleartool findmerge –all –ftag fooviewname -print –okgmerge
```

Each merge point gives me a prompt, with the default answer of [yes].  For example:

```
Needs Merge "/vob/foofilename.c" [(automatic) to /main/0 from /main/fooviewname/1 (base also /main/0)]
/vob/foofilename.c [yes]
```

I would like to change the default behavior of this command to use a default answer of [no].

Is there a cheap and simple way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If there's nothing in the man page, then probably not. You could write a wrapper program which does it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the default behavior of [`cleartool findmerge -okgmerge`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm).

I mentioned in "[Automatic merge in clearcase using cleartool findmerge command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655063/6309)" a way to reduce the occurrence of that message, using `-merge -abort`, instead of `-okgmerge`.